# PDO prepared statement not returning correct results (returns array filled with the variable name)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Been looking for ages how to get this prepared statement to work using both ? placeholders and named placeholders but no joy.

here is the code I have ended up with

```
<?php

require_once ("connection.php");

global $db;

$one = 'ID';
//$two = "QA-A";

$st = $db->prepare('select ? from EXECUTION_HISTORY');
//$array = array("ID", "QA-A");

 $st->bindParam(1, $one, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 //$st->bindParam(':two', $two);


 $st ->execute();

$data = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($data);
```

and this is the result it prints out

Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => ID ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => ID ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => ID )

if I change the select statement to

```
$st = $db->prepare('select ID from EXECUTION_HISTORY');
```

I get the real result

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 52 ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 53 )
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need to understand what placeholder is and what it is used for. And also decide, if you really need placeholders here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bindParam You're (surprise) binding a parameter to a placeholder in the query, not a field. Your prepared statement is actually prepared to this:

```
SELECT 'ID' FROM EXECUTION_HISTORY
```

Knowing this it is not strange you're getting the result you get.

So you don't need a paceholder here. But you do want some sanitizing and checks built in your query.

The way I do these things mostly is following:

```
$field = 'ID'; // Or from $_GET or something
$good = array('ID'); //holding every allowed field

$field = (in_array($field, $good)) ? $field : false;

if($field){
    $sql = "SELECT $field FROM EXECUTION_HISTORY WHERE someOtherField = :value";
    $stm = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->execute();

    print_r($stm->fetchAll());
}else{
    echo "Field is not allowed";
}
```